# System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, null, query-string

I get an error. How can I avoid this? Does anyone have any ideas? Note: The more I'm new :)

```
queryStringId.Text = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();
        SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand();
        baglanti.Open();
        komut.Connection = baglanti;
        komut.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SatilikDaire where ID=" + queryStringId.Text;
        komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataReader dr = komut.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Perhaps Request.QueryString["ID"] is null

Comment: Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). This is wide open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 1):

Just set a breakpoint and inspect which *element* is `null`. Either `Request` is `null` or `QueryString["ID"]` returns `null` or `queryStringId` is `null`.

Then once you have identified the *element* ensure it is not `null` anymore. If you don't know how to do that please go back to the basics of programming.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have learned a bit more basics. Thank you for your response and your suggestions

Comment: I made the following methods. How wrong I do not know how true
 `if (Request.QueryString["ID"] == null)
            {
                Label1.Text = ("kayıt yok");
            }
            else
            {
                queryStringId.Text = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();
                ............
                }
                else
                {
                    veriYok.Text = "Veri Yok :(";
                }`

Comment: @Enverköseler Loos ok but it is better to store the value of `Request.QueryString["ID"]` in a variable (e.g. `var id = Request.QueryString["ID"]`) and use this variable later on. This avoids retrieving the *ID* twice and is easier to debug as you can e.g. set conditions on the variable. Also please accept the answer if the issue is solved.

Comment: I am grateful to you for your interest and relevance. Thank I gave your vote